# Not understanding data types in mysql

Tags: mysql, database

I have a table in MySql that has all data types of char(). From what I understood the way I would query those columns I would have to use quotes because I am using strings. I did this and returned no data, but when I removed the quotes I received results.
These are the two queries,

```
select * from salef where streetnumber = 419;
select * from salef where streetnumber = '419';
```

The first one worked fine, but not the second.
When I run this query,

```
SELECT DATA_TYPE
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE
TABLE_NAME = 'salef' AND
COLUMN_NAME = 'street number';
```

I get the result of 
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/7E4iL.jpg

I'm confused. Is this a normal occurrence? And is there a way I can use quotes and get results?

Comment: Please post the result of the following query: `SHOW CREATE TABLE salef;`

Comment: Probably because `char` is blank padded, unlike `varchar` and if your column is wider than `char(3)`, it would need to be `...where streetnumber = '419   '`

Comment: Hi Probably this is a default conversion of data types. int to char it's OK, but string to char it's kind of impossible. If you don't need char type from any particular reason Use VARCHAR(10), in this case all you queries will pass

Comment: COLUMN_NAME = '**street number**'; whereas **streetnumber** = '419' ?

Comment: Paul, thats it! StreetName is char(5) so if I add two spaces in front with the quotes, the query works.